# MeteorJS how to add users from command prompt

Tags: javascript, meteor, account

How can I add users to my app outside of the deployed app itself? I don't want to allow users the ability to create accounts inside the app. Can I create some usernames and passwords from the command line and then give those to a few users to test the application?

Let me know if you need more information or if I am being unclear. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Granted that you have the`accounts-password` package installed. (You probably do since you already have login set up.)

You can launch `meteor shell` and enter

`Accounts.createUser({username: 'john', password: '12345'})`

This will take care of all the bcrypting for you. You should also be able to script this.

The relevant documentation with more option parameters is [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser).

Comment: It's kind of technically not the command shell but a Node REPL console, but it's still way easier than the other proposed solution! Could you also post a link to the relevant documentation/tech explanation of `meteor shell`?

Comment: Funny, grepping the docs gives me nothing about `meteor shell`

Comment: You might have to crawl around the forums, website, or some other place to get that data. The MDG hasn't been very consistent on documenting lately.

Comment: I'm finding grepping the docs and finding nothing is not at all unusual. :/

Answer (score 2):

You can add users from the command prompt but its not that easy.

Essentially you need to run something like this from mongo. For the sake of simplicity I'm not going to add in bcrypt code to make passwords.

Instead you can use a generic meteor password (default). For this create a meteor app, add in `accounts-password` and create a user account. Use the `services.password.bcrypt` value for all users). When you create a user account this bcrypt has represents the created user's password.

Then you can create a default script:

```
var user = {
  "createdAt": new Date(),
  "emails": [ ],
  "username": "<username>",
  "profile": {
    "name": "<Name>"
  },
  "services": {
    "password": {
      "bcrypt": "$2a$10$eUVSifclpbABCDEFGHIJKLmnopqr12323112ABBBCEDOINg2A7q0e"
    },
    "resume": {
      "loginTokens": [ ]
    }
  }
}

db.users.add(user);
```

Then you can run this script (be sure to replace the  and  values. Also the _id if you can with a random string. This way mongodb will generate the _id as an `ObjectID`.

Then you can run this script (if you called it myjsfile.js) from the command prompt (if mongo is on the local port 3001):

```
mongo localhost:3001/meteor myjsfile.js
```

Comment: Use this if you run in production( where you don't have a meteor shell )